# Trying to get the json data located on http end point

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, http, get

I am trying to get the http end point data which is in json format using the below code but the output which I receive is not as it's visible at the link posted below. Can you share your inputs on how to do this?

Code :-

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://headers.jsontest.com/')

print( r.json() )
```

Output what I am receiving :-

```
{u'Host': u'headers.jsontest.com', u'User-Agent': u'python-requests/2.18.4', u'Accept': u'*/*', u'X-Cloud-Trace-Context': u'9034981eba16654b42daa1d10f503cab/2431501768736408823'}
```

Output what I would like to see( Pls open the link ) :-
http://headers.jsontest.com/

```
   {
       "X-Cloud-Trace-Context": "37e49d37206663367d675c2ff01db8a2/15699104367477007142",
       "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
       "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
       "X-IMForwards": "20",
       "Host": "headers.jsontest.com",
       "Referer": "http://www.jsontest.com/",
       "Via": "1.1 ironport-s680.air-worldwide.com:80 (Cisco-WSA/9.0.1-162)",
       "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36",
       "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"
    }
```

Comment: That's just the string representation of the Python dictionary corresponding to the parsed JSON in the URL. They represent the same data. What's your issue? Do you not like the formatting?

EDIT: Nevermind, it seems they're not exactly the same. The output of that URL is simply the HTTP headers of the request mirrored in the response as @Yotam Salmon said in his answer

Comment: I would like to get the json data located at the http end point... How can I do it?

Comment: You will have to fake the headers by passing a `headers` dict to `requests.get`, which then begs the question: what's the point of setting the headers, making a request and then getting back the same headers you just set? Assuming you are not testing that web service...

Comment: Without any headers, you can use `import json`; `json.dumps(r.json())` to get rid of the unicode etc. But like @DeepSpace said, I'm not sure what you're doing.

Comment: I would like to get the json data from http endpoints.  Output what I am receiving is incorrect.  My intent is I am given multiple imaginery server names and I need to check every server and see if there is any json data that exists or not.. if it exists I have to retrieve the json object and do some computation for few columns in my code...

Answer (score 1):

In fact you do get the correct HTTP response. It just depends on how you send it (through browser or an empty request from Python)

When you open it through your browser, additional headers are added by the browser itself. When you send your request through `requests` in Python, those headers are not sent.

The HTTP response just mirrors the headers we sent to it. So if you want to see the same response, you'll have to send the headers manually using `requests`.

You can add them like that:

```
headers = {
       "X-Cloud-Trace-Context": "37e49d37206663367d675c2ff01db8a2/15699104367477007142",
       "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
       "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
       "X-IMForwards": "20",
       "Host": "headers.jsontest.com",
       "Referer": "http://www.jsontest.com/",
       "Via": "1.1 ironport-s680.air-worldwide.com:80 (Cisco-WSA/9.0.1-162)",
       "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36",
       "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"
    }

import requests
r = requests.get('http://headers.jsontest.com/', headers = headers)

print( r.json() )
```

This returns:

```
{u'Via': u'1.1 ironport-s680.air-worldwide.com:80 (Cisco-WSA/9.0.1-162)', u'Acce
pt-Language': u'en-US,en;q=0.9', u'X-IMForwards': u'20', u'Accept': u'text/html,
application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8', u'
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': u'1', u'Host': u'headers.jsontest.com', u'Referer':
u'http://www.jsontest.com/', u'X-Cloud-Trace-Context': u'37e49d37206663367d675c2
ff01db8a2/14205897462093082399', u'User-Agent': u'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; W
in64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/53
7.36'}
```

Comment: My expected output is the one which comes out when I open the link which I shared in the browser... I would like to see the same json data when I run the python code

Comment: Yes, but the expected output is expected from sending a request **from a browser**. When you send it headerless, like in your question, the response will be like it is. You have to fake yourself being a browser by adding the headers, as I have shown. All what the website does is to print what the headers you sent are. If you send none, It will print the minimal headers. If you send headers (like in my answer) it will return your beloved headers.

Comment: @Teja Do you understand the *meaning* of the information you are getting back in the json?

Comment: Yes... but what I am seeing in this answer is not what I am expecting...

Comment: And if you want it to be **exact**, you can take `r.text` and not `r.json()`

Comment: I dont know what headers will be there in the http end point... how can I specify the headers... ? I have 1000's of servers and I need to go to http://<servername>.xyz.com/status and get the json object if the server physically exists...

Comment: Wait, can you define your task again? You may have got us a bit confused.

Comment: If I can understand how to get the json object from a remote http end point I can do it for 'n' no. of servers...  My task is simple... I have 'n' no. of server names in a text file. I have to read the file line by line , get the server name and do http request at this link http://<servername>.xyz.com/status ( xyz is confidential I cant share it ) and then get the json object from that link if server exists... if server doesnt exist I can go to the next server until end...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165931/discussion-between-teja-and-yotam-salmon).

Comment: So you are on the right path. There are no real issues, since the json you're seeing is the json the server has sent. It differs from the json you see in your browser just because the different ways your request is sent. But you definitely can proceed and use your code snippet to check if servers are up, since it's alright.

Comment: So how do I get the json object as per my question?